# TypeScript Casting for JQuery button?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm getting confused trying to implement TypeScript for the first time in a project which uses jQuery.

This works:

```
(document.getElementById('btnTest') as HTMLButtonElement).addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    testCode();
});
```

However, the following jQuery generates TypeScript errors ***(Conversion of type 'JQuery' to type 'HTMLButtonElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other)***:

```
($('#btnTest') as HTMLButtonElement).addEventListener('click', function (event: any) {
    testCode();
});
```

Any idea how to properly tell TypeScript that `$('#btnTest').addEventListener()` is valid (ie, I know I'll return a button)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `$('#btnTest')` is `jQuery`, where `$('#btnTest').get(0)` is `HTMLButtonElement`. To add an event in jquery you use `on`

Comment: Bonk (head on table). Thank you! So distracted by the TS error I forgot to consider that.